# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration'

Tags: c#

I am able to build the application but while running it shows below exception.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Verdana";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: .7em;
        color: black;
      }

      p {
        font-family: "Verdana";
        font-weight: normal;
        color: black;
        margin-top: -5px
      }

      `enter code here` b {
        font-family: "Verdana";
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        margin-top: -5px
      }

      H1 {
        font-family: "Verdana";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 18pt;
        color: red
      }

      H2 {
        font-family: "Verdana";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14pt;
        color: maroon
      }

      pre {
        font-family: "Consolas", "Lucida Console", Monospace;
        font-size: 11pt;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
        line-height: 14pt
      }

      .marker {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .version {
        color: gray;
      }

      .error {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .expandable {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: navy;
        cursor: hand;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
        pre {
          width: 440px;
          overflow: auto;
          white-space: pre-wrap;
          word-wrap: break-word;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        pre {
          width: 280px;
        }
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="white">

    <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

                <h2> <i>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)</i> </h2></span>

    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

                <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

                <br><br>

                <b> Exception Details: </b>System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)<br><br>

                <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

                <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <code>

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>

                <br>

                <b>Assembly Load Trace:</b> The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' could not be loaded.<br><br>

                <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <code><pre>

    Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Running under executable  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    --- A detailed error log follows. 

    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration
     (Partial)
    WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
    WRN: Assembly Name: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration | Domain ID: 2
    WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
    WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
    WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
    WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
    WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin
    Calling assembly : (Unknown).
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/bin/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.DLL.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\web.config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 3.0.0.0 redirected to 3.5.0.0.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/bin/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.DLL.
    WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
    ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
    </pre></code>

                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>

                <br>

                <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

                <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <code><pre>

    [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

    [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
       System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

    [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean&amp; isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
       System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
       System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9924680
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
    </pre></code>

                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>

                <br>

                <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

                <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1038.0

                </font>

  </body>

</html>
<!-- 
    [FileLoadException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    [FileLoadException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
       at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
       at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
    [ConfigurationErrorsException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
       at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
       at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
       at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
       at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
    [HttpException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
       at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
    -->


**adding log of fuslogexe** *** Assembly Binder Log Entry (12/10/2015 @ 10:12:33 PM) *** The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available. Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe --- A detailed error log follows. === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http.Formatting (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly: WRN:
Assembly Name: System.Net.Http.Formatting | Domain ID: 3 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully
specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue. LOG:
Appbase = file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e09d11e4
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e09d11e4 LOG: AppName = d81f7128 Calling assembly : (Unknown). === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Policy not being applied to reference
at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting
download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/bin/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll LOG: Entering download cache setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Redirect found in application configuration
file: 5.2.2.0 redirected to 5.2.3.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: The post-policy assembly reference requires probing again.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/bin/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Assembly download
was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll LOG: Entering download cache setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found. ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040. ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly
(hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated. *** Assembly Binder Log Entry (12/10/2015 @ 10:12:33 PM) *** The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available. Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe --- A detailed error log follows. === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http.Formatting (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly: WRN:
Assembly Name: System.Net.Http.Formatting | Domain ID: 3 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully
specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue. LOG:
Appbase = file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e09d11e4
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e09d11e4 LOG: AppName = d81f7128 Calling assembly : (Unknown). === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Policy not being applied to reference
at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting
download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/bin/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll LOG: Entering download cache setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Redirect found in application configuration
file: 5.2.2.0 redirected to 5.2.3.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: The post-policy assembly reference requires probing again.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
ASP.NET Files/root/e09d11e4/d81f7128/System.Net.Http.Formatting/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/Projects/MSPOD/dev/Services/PanDa.Data.Service/bin/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL. LOG: Assembly download
was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\TFS\Projects\MSPOD\dev\Services\PanDa.Data.Service\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll LOG: Entering download cache setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found. ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040. ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly
(hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Could you provide the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-install Unity package by calling nuget command:

```
Update-Package –reinstall Unity
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have unity in your project it seems. In package manager console type;

`Install-Package Unity`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/

Comment: I am adding Fuslogvw log messsage.

Comment: Note that if it's looking for a specific version, you also have to pass in the version via -Version flag. (Also note that in my case it was looking for version 3.5.0, which is *actually* 3.5.1404 for some reason.)